# What is the default threading model used by Apache Camel?

Tags: concurrency, apache-camel

Apache Camel 2.19 here. What is the default concurrency behavior if no special `<threadPool/>` tag is defined inside the `CamelContext`?

Does Camel default to being single threaded? Does it provide a standard `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPool` that ships with the Java Concurrency API?

To be clear, I understand that I can define a *custom* `ThreadPool` by provideding a `<threadPool/>` definition in the `CamelContext`...I'm just wondering what Camel uses if I *don't* do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case the [default thread pool profile](https://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html) configuration will be used to create thread pools.

The default profile config is:

- poolSize="10"
- maxPoolSize="20"
- maxQueueSize="1000"
- allowCoreThreadTimeOut="false"
- rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns"

Have look at the class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExecutorServiceManager](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.19.x/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultExecutorServiceManager.java) for more details.